# IndexError: string index out of range on reading files from ftp

Tags: python

I am newbie in Python and I'm trying to get files from an ftp directory. I get this error every time I run this code. When I run this it reads all the files in the directory and then it gives me an error on `callback = mylist[1]`. The first part defines the function and the other part is where I call the files:

```
from ftplib import FTP
    import os, sys

    def rCallback3(filename):
    new_filename = "rrrr/files/%s" % just_filename
    retval = subprocess.call(["/usr/local/bin/r.py", filename])
    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
    return retval
```

I have removed some code......

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.192.0.195', 'ro', 'Password')
files = ftp.dir()
dirlist = ['/',rCallback3]

while (True):
    # Go through each of the directories
    for mylist in dirlist:
        check_dir = mylist[0]
        callback = mylist[1]-- here i get this error 

        # get the list of files in the directory
        filelist = os.listdir(check_dir)
        for this_file in filelist:
            if ((this_file == ".") or (this_file == "..") or (this_file == "donecsvfiles")or (this_file == "doneringofiles")):
                print "Skipping self and parent"
                continue

            full_filename = "%s/%s"%(check_dir, this_file)

            # Get the modification time of the file
            first_stat = os.stat(full_filename)[8]

            # Sleep for 1 second
            time.sleep(1)

            # Get the modification time again
            second_stat = os.stat(full_filename)[8]

            # If the modication time has not changed, then the file is stable
            # and can be sent to the callback
            if (first_stat == second_stat):
              callback(full_filename)
```

I get this error now.

```
{"iv":
  { "result": "ok" }
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ringo.py", line 51, in <module>
    reader = csv.reader(open(csvfile, 'r'))
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '//tmp'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dirmon.py", line 83, in <module>
    callback(full_filename)
  File "./dirmon.py", line 46, in ringoCallback3
    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link
```

Comment: Print statements are your friend! print mylist just after `for mylist in dirlist:` and you'll see that it's '/', not a list.

Comment: @tdelaney: The stated error would not occur if the string were longer...

Comment: @ScottHunter - meaning..., what? He'd have the same bug and it would hit a little further down the code. The print statement would still show the error.

Answer (score 0):

`dirlist[0]` is a single-character string (`'/'`), so `mylist` is initially that string; since it has only 1 character, there is nothing at `mylist[1]`.

Maybe you don't really want to be iterating over `dirlist`, or maybe it should be `[['/',rCallback3]]`?

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the program is this line:

```
dirlist = ['/',rCallback3]
```

which assigns the name `dirlist` to the list `['/',ringoCallback3]`.  You then have a for-loop:

```
for mylist in dirlist:
```

that iterates over `dirlist` and yields each item as `mylist`.

**The first item in `dirlist` (and therefore the first value for `mylist`) is the string `'/'`.**

So, when Python first encounters these two lines:

```
check_dir = mylist[0]
callback = mylist[1]
```

it treats them as being equivalent to:

```
check_dir = '/'[0]
callback = '/'[1]
```

The second one raises an `IndexError` because `'/'` has only one character but you told Python to get a nonexistent second character at index `1`:

```
>>> '/'[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks icodez but I have only one directory on it which  has multiple files in it. when i use callback = mylist[0] then i get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dirmon.py", line 83, in <module>
    callback(full_filename)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable